# What is the simplest way to create a shaped window in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, shaped-window

I'd like to create a simple shaped window in wxPython. More or less I want to do the wx equivalent to Tkinter's **self.overrideredirect(1)** (It get's rid of the default OS boarder), then round the corners on the window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a shaped frame demo in the wxPython demos.  I apologize for the indirect source. They originally came as a windows installer [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.11.0/wxPython2.8-win32-docs-demos-2.8.11.0.exe/download):

[source code](http://wxwidgets2.8.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.8.9.1/dir_af07dda85bd164ae7e9ac58cca6a4dd4.html)

You'll want to look at shaped_frame_mobile.py or shaped_frame.py, which both call images.py from that listing for the sample window bitmap.  It's not the exact equivalent to `overrideredirect` since you will have to provide an image to be drawn for the frame, but it could still help you accomplish something similar.

The important parts are the functions that set the window shape based on the bitmap and handle the wx.EVT_PAINT event:

```
def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
    r = wx.RegionFromBitmap(self.bmp)
    self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)

def OnPaint(self, evt):
    dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
    dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
```

Edit - Here's an altered `shaped_frame_mobile.py` that loads the .png image specified in the IMAGE_PATH variable. Change that to point to your image:

```
import wx

# Create a .png image with something drawn on a white background
# and put the path to it here.
IMAGE_PATH = '/python26/projects/shapedwin/image.png'


class ShapedFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Shaped Window",
                style = wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER )
        self.hasShape = False
        self.delta = wx.Point(0,0)

        # Load the image
        image = wx.Image(IMAGE_PATH, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
        image.SetMaskColour(255,255,255)
        image.SetMask(True)            
        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage(image)

        self.SetClientSize((self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight()))
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
        self.SetWindowShape()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_CREATE, self.SetWindowShape)

    def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
        r = wx.RegionFromBitmap(self.bmp)
        self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)

    def OnDoubleClick(self, evt):
        if self.hasShape:
            self.SetShape(wx.Region())
            self.hasShape = False
        else:
            self.SetWindowShape()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        origin = self.GetPosition()
        self.delta = wx.Point(pos.x - origin.x, pos.y - origin.y)

    def OnMouseMove(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            newPos = (pos.x - self.delta.x, pos.y - self.delta.y)
            self.Move(newPos)

    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    ShapedFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, though it references an "images" module. I'm not exactly sure which module that is. Do you have any clue?

Comment: It's the `images.py` file from the source link above. You can either drop that into the same directory as the others, or get rid of `import images` and load your own bitmap in place of the `images.getVippiBitmap()` line.  I don't know why the demo uses a python module to provide an image.

Comment: @Anteater7171 Added the altered code to my answer.  It's easier to show than explain.

Comment: great answer, FYI `wx.RegionFromBitmap` has been replaced with `wx.Region` and `wx.BitmapFromImage` is replaced with `wx.Bitmap`

Answer (score 0):

Guys I know there is a accepted answer, I used that answer in ubuntu with python 2.x, however when I tried to use it on windows python 3.x it didn't work. So I fixed it after small research (wx.Region needs a transparent color, see below code). And changed several depreciated methods:

```
import wx

IMAGE_PATH = ".\Images\myImageFile.png"

class ShapedFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Shaped Window",
                style = wx.FRAME_SHAPED | wx.SIMPLE_BORDER )
        self.hasShape = False
        self.delta = wx.Point(0,0)

        # Load the image

        self.bmp = wx.Image(IMAGE_PATH, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
        #self.bmp = wx.Bitmap(image)

        self.transparentColour = wx.Colour(255, 255, 255, alpha=wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE)

        self.SetClientSize((self.bmp.GetWidth(), self.bmp.GetHeight()))
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0,0, True)
        self.SetWindowShape()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnDoubleClick)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_UP, self.OnExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_WINDOW_CREATE, self.SetWindowShape)

    def SetWindowShape(self, evt=None):
        r = wx.Region(self.bmp , self.transparentColour)
        self.hasShape = self.SetShape(r)

    def OnDoubleClick(self, evt):
        if self.hasShape:
            self.SetShape(wx.Region())
            self.hasShape = False
        else:
            self.SetWindowShape()

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0, True)

    def OnExit(self, evt):
        self.Close()

    def OnLeftDown(self, evt):
        self.CaptureMouse()
        pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
        origin = self.GetPosition()
        self.delta = wx.Point(pos.x - origin.x, pos.y - origin.y)

    def OnMouseMove(self, evt):
        if evt.Dragging() and evt.LeftIsDown():
            pos = self.ClientToScreen(evt.GetPosition())
            newPos = (pos.x - self.delta.x, pos.y - self.delta.y)
            self.Move(newPos)

    def OnLeftUp(self, evt):
        if self.HasCapture():
            self.ReleaseMouse()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    ShapedFrame().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```