# wxPython Transparent Frame - Display Text

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have followed the tutorial here: [Transparent Frames](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Transparent%20Frames)

How can I make it so only the text from `TextCtrl` has 100% opacity while the rest of the window is invisible? What i mean is, I want an invisible window except for the text in `TextCtrl`.

I am on Windows 7, using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial you linked:

> Only top-level controls can be transparent; no other controls can

A textctrl or statictxt, of course, is not a top level control.

There is [this](http://www.keacher.com/994/transparent-static-text-in-wxpython/) option, which I believe only works ontop of other opaque objects not on a transparent panel.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873063/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-create-a-shaped-window-in-wxpython) shows how to draw an arbitrarily shaped window. If you combine (somehow) the above two, you should be able to get text against a transparent background. Other than that, good luck.