# Different shapes of windows in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

normally when you make a window in tkinter using Tk(), the standard shape of the window would be a square. Is there any way we can make the shape anything else?

Comment: No you can not and why do you need to change the shape of your tkinter window huh?

Comment: At least there is no built-in way to do this, you would need to find a hack around.

Comment: Your OS / window manager is responsible for the outer border of the window. You could create a borderless window, try to create a [transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window) and draw the shape you want on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also relatively new to custom GUIs in Python myself. I've been searching the Internet for an answer to a similar question for several hours now. As awesome as Tkinter is, it appears to me that its capabilities are restricted to standard-looking, *rectangular* GUI objects. On the one hand, this greatly simplifies coding in Python. On the other, an application could often benefit from a customized GUI. (*Imagine a dialog window in the image/shape of an ancient scroll used in an RPG game interface driven by Python code.*) Using tricks like transparency might work in Tk. But, all widgets in that transparent window will also become transparent. So, it would be tricky to get right. However, it is common knowledge that more advanced programming languages do allow you to utilize arbitrary window, frame, button shapes, etc., that might be appropriate for such a game interface as mentioned above.

Then I found wxPython. https://wxpython.org/ From what I've read about it so far, that library does have deeper access to the more abstract classes built-in to the OS from which you can build a frame, or any GUI object, of any arbitrary shape or from any image. The major downside is that you have to build these objects from scratch using OOP syntax similar to C++. That requires a steeper learning curve than what is needed for Tkinter. But, I think it's worth the effort and I will start that learning process shortly.

Here is an example from Python Programming Studio. Unfortunately, the code listing does not appear to be rendered properly on that page; (at least on my browser.) But it does show that it is possible to implement a custom-shaped window using wxPython:

https://www.pythonstudio.us/wxpython/how-do-i-make-a-nonrectangular-frame.html

Fortunately, there is a wxPython thread here with much clearer coding examples:

[What is the simplest way to create a shaped window in wxPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873063/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-create-a-shaped-window-in-wxpython)

There are several other tutorials at the wxPyWiki, (and other places), that will at least give you an idea of what wxPython can do:

https://wiki.wxpython.org/

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create windows of any shape other than a rectangle.

Comment: But you can create the illusion of another shape.